# Example of a sequence having 3 subsequences going to infinity, minus infinity and zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am struggling with few basic sequences, hoping someone can help me.

a) I am looking for an example of the sequence $ (x_n)^\infty_n=_1$ whose terms are different and has three subsequences, one going to infinity, another to minus infinity and another to zero.

b) Prove whether it is possible to have a sequence $ (x_n)^\infty_n=_1$ that has t subsequences converging to real numbers $ {a_1, a_2, a_3,... ,a_t} $ but does NOT containing any of the $ a_t $.

For a), I was thinking about $ -1, 0, 1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3. $
For b i know that rationals are countable as a set and can be enumerated, but I can't see any sequence that would converge to them and not contain them (Can't think of the contradiction though).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, .... might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for A:  Name a sequence that converges to infinity, another that converges to 0, and a third that converges to minus infinity. $a_i,b_i,c_i$.  Now just make a new sequence $d$ such that for any natural number $n$ writing it in mod 3 language as $3q+r$ where $0\leq r\leq 2$,   just define $d_n=d_{3k+r}$ and then make it $a_k$ if $r=0$,  $b_k$ if $r=1$,  $c_k$ if $r=3$.   The terms should all be different, but that should be easy enough to do

For B:  Can you extend the logic in the construction of part A?

Comment: For B: so you mean to create n sequences that converge into each a, and then making new sequence with them? The problem is with the constrain that none of the rational numbers can belong to that sequence hm

Comment: That's easy,  just make your sequence all the rational number minus a shrinking number